# ¿Como puedo sumar 2 listas de tipo objeto? C#

Tags: c#, lista, object

tengo una duda en cuanto a suma de valores en 2 listas, de la siguiente manera

lista1: (tomando en cuenta que los valores son "nombre", "tipo", "cantidad")
{a,b,23}
{c,d,2}
{e,f,5}
{g,h,10}

lista2: (tomando en cuenta que los valores son "nombre", "tipo", "cantidad")
{i,j,1}
{k,l,2}
{c,d,8}*
{m,n,15}
{e,f,80}*
{o,p,46}
{g,h,80}*
{q,r,56}
{s,t,13}

los datos estoy guardando en una nueva lista, la cual en teoria tendría que ser la siguiente

lista3 (o resultante): (tomando en cuenta que los valores son "nombre", "tipo", "cantidad")
{a,b,23}
{i,j,1}
{k,l,2}
{c,d,10}*
{m,n,15}
{e,f,85}*
{o,p,46}
{g,h,90}*
{q,r,56}
{s,t,13}

Por ejemplo se agregan en la nueva lista los datos tanto de la primera como de la segunda sumando los datos que tienen coincidencia, los otros que no tienen coincidencia, unicamente se agrega en la nueva.

por el momento tengo esta parte son sacados de sql

```
List<BSLBalance> lista = new List<BSLBalance>();
     foreach (var item in ListadoCalculoVentasInventario)
                    {
                        bool has1 = ListadoPedidos.Any(cus => cus.nombre == item.nombre.ToString() && cus.tipo == item.tipo.ToString());
                        if (has1 == true)
                        {
                            foreach (var i in ListadoPedidos)
                            {
                                if (item.nombre == i.nombre && item.tipo == i.tipo)
                                {
                                    BSLBalance obj = new BSLBalance();
                                    obj.nombre = item.nombre;
                                    obj.tipo = item.tipo;
                                    int a = int.Parse(item.cantidad.ToString());
                                    int b = int.Parse(i.cantidad.ToString());
                                    obj.cantidad = a + b;
                                    lista.Add(obj);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            BSLBalance obj = new BSLBalance();
                            obj.nombre = item.nombre;
                            obj.tipo = item.tipo;
                            int a = int.Parse(item.cantidad.ToString());
                            obj.cantidad = a;
                            lista.Add(obj);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Podrias poner que intentaste hasta ahora? y un ejemplo de codigo de tus listas y objetos?

Comment: Listo, perdón por no poner antes.

Comment: Y dentro de ese codigo, cual es cada lista? por favor, trata que tu pregunta se entienda. Lo que tratas de hacer no es dificil, pero es dificil ayudarte si no se entiende que tenes.

Comment: Cuando mencionas *sumando los datos que tienen coincidencia* a que campo te refieres?, por lo que se ve lo unico que necesitas es unir las dos lista y hacer un *group by*(por el/los campos que coincidan) y luego sumar la propiedad cantidad.

Comment: @Elcainas muchas gracias, probaré con el group by, en sí eso era lo que necesitaba.